Correlating two perpendicular frames captured by two perpendicular cameras using trackpy
I want to produce the 3D trajectory of micro-organisms using the data produced by two simultaneous and perpendicular image frames. Here is what a frame of such a video looks like after treatment removing the median (i.e. the background):
Image captured by the camera
So far I've applied trackpy's suggested method and I managed to extract the Dataframe corresponding to each camera, which have as keys :
[ 0; y; x; mass; size; ecc; signal; raw_mass; ep; frame; particle]

I am now looking to correlate the two Dataframe so that it matches on the vertical y position which is common to both cameras.
I've been manipulating the dataframes I obtained and I produced a new column called difference in these dataframes using the following code :
df_camA = df_camA.sort_values(by=['particle', 'frame'])

df_camA['difference'] = df_camA.groupby('particle')['y'].diff()

corresponding to the difference in vertical positions of a given particle between two successive frames. I then tried to make these values correspond between each table using :
df_camA['difference'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_camB['difference'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
difference_vectors_A = df_camA.groupby('particle')['difference'].apply(list)
difference_vectors_B= df_camB.groupby('particle')['difference'].apply(list)

liste_vect_A=[]
for vector in difference_vectors_A:
   liste_vect_A.append(np.array(vector))

liste_vect_B=[]
for vector in difference_vectors_B:
   liste_vect_B.append(np.array(vector))

i=0
for vect_A in liste_vect_A:
    dist=10000
    normA=np.linalg.norm(vect_A)
    if normA!=0:
        index_min=0
        j=0
        for vect_B in liste_vect_B:
            if np.linalg.norm(vect_B)!=0:
                diff=np.linalg.norm(vect_B-vect_A)
                if diff<dist:
                    dist=diff
                    index_min=j
                else:
                    j+=1
                    continue
            else:
                j+=1
                continue
        index_list.append(index_min)
    else:
        index_list.append(i)
        i+=1

I did this because the vertical position isn't absolute in both cameras as the elevation is roughly and not exactly the same.
However, since the detection might differ between both cameras, the arrays have different lengths as the same particle may not be detected in both dataframes and thus this method doesn't seem to work.
Does anyone have insights of what I could potentially do to solve this problem ?
Any input is welcome

Note that this problem doesn’t always have a unique solution. Two particles at the same y coordinate cannot be disambiguated. Maybe if you match the full y function over time for each particle you can get more robust results.

more example data would help (me) grasp the full problem, i.e. video of both cameras viewing the same scene.

So, if I understand right, your goal is to match the particles detected in both cameras based on their vertical position sand the challenges arise because of detection inconsistencies, for instance that a particle may appear in only one camera and differences in array lengths make direct correlation infeasible.
What I would suggest is matching particles between the two cameras frame by frame based on the proximity of their y coordinates, using a defined threshold to account for slight misalignments. To do so, you need a matching function iterates through frames, computes the absolute distance between y positions for all possible particle pairs, and selects the closest match if the distance is below the threshold.
Bit, you may have unmatched particles. So, what you can do is to also have an extended function includes particles only detected in one camera by appending rows with null values for missing data.
Here is what I suggest (this works on the sample data I provide, so check if it works for your. Or upload sample data)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

df_camA = pd.DataFrame({
    'frame': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'particle': [0, 1, 0, 1],
    'y': [10, 20, 11, 21],
    'x': [5, 15, 6, 16]
})

df_camB = pd.DataFrame({
    'frame': [1, 1, 2],
    'particle': [0, 2, 0],
    'y': [10.5, 19.8, 10.8],
    'x': [4.5, 14.5, 5.8]
})

def match_particles(df_camA, df_camB, threshold=1.0):
    matched_data = []
    for frame in df_camA['frame'].unique():
        frameA = df_camA[df_camA['frame'] == frame]
        frameB = df_camB[df_camB['frame'] == frame]
        for _, rowA in frameA.iterrows():
            closest_particle = None
            min_distance = float('inf')
            for _, rowB in frameB.iterrows():
                dist = abs(rowA['y'] - rowB['y'])
                if dist < min_distance and dist <= threshold:
                    min_distance = dist
                    closest_particle = rowB
            if closest_particle is not None:
                matched_data.append({
                    'frame': frame,
                    'particle_camA': rowA['particle'],
                    'particle_camB': closest_particle['particle'],
                    'y_camA': rowA['y'],
                    'y_camB': closest_particle['y'],
                    'x_camA': rowA['x'],
                    'x_camB': closest_particle['x']
                })
    return pd.DataFrame(matched_data)

def include_unmatched(df_camA, df_camB, threshold=1.0):
    matched_df = match_particles(df_camA, df_camB, threshold)

    unmatched_camA = df_camA[~df_camA['particle'].isin(matched_df['particle_camA'])]
    unmatched_camA = unmatched_camA.assign(
        particle_camB=np.nan, y_camB=np.nan, x_camB=np.nan
    ).rename(columns={'particle': 'particle_camA', 'y': 'y_camA', 'x': 'x_camA'})

    unmatched_camB = df_camB[~df_camB['particle'].isin(matched_df['particle_camB'])]
    unmatched_camB = unmatched_camB.assign(
        particle_camA=np.nan, y_camA=np.nan, x_camA=np.nan
    ).rename(columns={'particle': 'particle_camB', 'y': 'y_camB', 'x': 'x_camB'})

    final_df = pd.concat([matched_df, unmatched_camA, unmatched_camB], ignore_index=True)
    return final_df

matched_df = include_unmatched(df_camA, df_camB, threshold=1.0)

print(matched_df)



Which gives you
   frame  particle_camA  particle_camB  y_camA  y_camB  x_camA  x_camB
0      1            0.0            0.0    10.0    10.5     5.0     4.5
1      1            1.0            2.0    20.0    19.8    15.0    14.5
2      2            0.0            0.0    11.0    10.8     6.0     5.8

